# React-Native splash screen VERY slow

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen

I am using react native to build an app and for the splash screen I have an image. Running the project through XCode is painfully slow.

I was wondering is this a normal occurrence, or is there ways to speed up the load time like compressing the image etc.

I realise that loading images is always going to be slow, but if I could get some guidance on the matter it would be great.

Comment: 'Running the project through XCode is painfully slow.' is it slow when you run it without splash screen? :) because that just doesn't make sense. Launching ios apps from Xcode is always slow, but that isn't about splash screen. What's your image size? You may consider minifying it. If your concern is about Splash Screen showing for too long, like 15 seconds, that's because your app takes it time to transform files

Comment: @EnieJakiro The image is 640x960, wouldn't have thought it would have caused that many issues. It is slow without the splash screen, but not this slow. It takes a long time for the splash screen to appear and then a long tome for the server to load. It almost takes a minute for the app to load.

Comment: May I ask your computer specs, since we're working on local environment, everything can affect your load time. Sometimes I even need to close Spotify app to get things work faster

Comment: Mac Book Air (2012) 
OSX - El Capitan V 10.11.6
Processor - 1.8GHz 
Memory - 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

Comment: Well, your setup is kinda week but you know, can't tell for sure.

Comment: It has never been this bad. Maybe its just XCode, I have run Rails, word press and an array of other projects.

Comment: Yes XCode is one giant software. I hope things get better.

Comment: How many 'screens' do you have in your app? Is your app slow only at splash screen? How does it behave after splash?

Comment: Any resolution to this issue @user2026178? In the simulator mine launches fine but on device it hangs on the splash screen for up to a minute.